# Colon operator ":" before function call (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, url-scheme

I was looking at the source to a website and I saw this strange href attribute in a link and I can't figure out what it's doing.  It doesn't look like valid javascript.  I thought maybe the colon operator here was being used as a way to access the function property `popDocWin` in the object `javascript` but when I tried to emulate that syntax on a test function it wouldn't work.

```
<a href="javascript:popDocWin('aviewdocument.aspx?t=4704396');">Exterior Adjustable</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`javascript:` is a psuedo-protocol meaning "run the code following this." You can use it (in a browser context) anywhere a URL is valid. In this case, clicking the link "follows" the link, and the act of following the link runs the JavaScript rather than going anywhere. (This is also how [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) work.) So the `javascript:` part of that isn't JavaScript, just the part *after* it.

---

However, something that looks like that *is* valid JavaScript: If it weren't in a URL, it would create a [*labelled statement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12). The primary use of labelled statements in JavaScript is breaking outer loops from within inner ones, like this:

```
var x, y;
outer: for (x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
    for (y = 0; y < 5; ++y) {
        if (x === 2 && y === 3) {
            break outer;
        }
        snippet.show("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
x = 0, y = 0
x = 0, y = 1
x = 0, y = 2
x = 1, y = 0
```

Note how the `x` loop was terminated from within the `y` loop.

```js
var snippet = {
  show: function(msg) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>" + msg + "</p>");
  }
};

var x, y;
outer: for (x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
    for (y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        if (x === 1 && y === 1) {
            break outer;
        }
        snippet.show("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The colon is not before the function call, its after the word javascript!

It is telling your browser it should execute the javasript code after the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Well, href isn't a place where your browser would expect javascript code, so `javascript:` tells the browser that it should treat whatever is after it as javascript.